# how to launch owasp zap from robot framework

Tags: robotframework, owasp

I'm trying to get my RobotFramwork test to start OWASP ZAP application.

```
Start OWASP ZAP
[Documentation]    Starts OWASP ZAP
${handle}=    Start process    C:\\Program Files\\OWASP\\Zed Attack Proxy\\ZAP.exe
Sleep    60s
Process Should Be Running    ${handle}
[Return]    ${handle}
```

This does nothing (except of course waits for 60s). The ZAP UI does not appear at any point... With Notepad, Paint.NET,... this works just fine. The UIs appear just as expected. But with OWASP ZAP the test log looks like this:

[log.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRMpr.jpg)

How should OWASP ZAP be launched from Robot Framework test case?

Comment: Have you tried examining the return code, stdout, and/or stderr with [get process result](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Get%20Process%20Result) to get clues as to why it's not starting?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using [Process library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html). You can create a someName.bat (It should call your exe file.) and place same in the class path of your test cases. Now instead of calling exe with path call file bat file as mentioned in the document.It should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate why a .bat file will make it work, when the .exe doesn't? Asking out of curiosity.